# Copy conditional formatting of non-adjacent cells to other rows (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Have 3 sets of 5 columns
1 column Size (eg volume)
2 column Price
3 column Unit price
4 column
5 column
... repeat 2 times

Conditional formatting to find highest unit price between B2, K2, P2
Conditional formatting to find lowest price between B2, K2, P2

Can achieve this for one row.
CANNOT for the life of me figure out how to copy this for next 200 rows in sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to Highlight the Maximum in each row for column B,K and P
Also for the Minimum in each row for column B,K and P

1- Select column B
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=B2=MAX(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want

Repeat the same for Minimum:
1- Select column B
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=B2=MIN(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want

For column K:
1- Select column K
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=K2=MAX(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want
For Minimum:
1- Select column K
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=K2=MIN(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want

For column P:
1- Select column P
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=P2=MAX(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want
For Minimum:
1- Select column P
2- Conditional Formatting, New Rule
3- Click on Use a formula to determine which cells to format
4- In the box under Format values where this formula is True
5- Write `=P2=MIN(B2,K2,P2)`
6- Choose the format you want

Just don't use $ in your formula specially for rows

[image]

[image]

If you don't need the whole column, you can use `Format Painter` for each cell in the same column (for example B2, B5, B10 select B2 after applying the conditional formatting, click on `Format Painter` and select B5)
`Format Painter` can copy the conditional formatting
The same for P2, P5 you have to select P2 after applying the conditional formatting, click Format Painter and select P5